# Is it normal for my __RequestVerificationToken to be different with every request?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, csrf

I've Google'd, but haven't been able to determine if ASP.NET MVC's v4 RequestVerificationToken should be different for every request?

I notice this in all environments, even when running on a single server. The user is logged in, but when refreshing the page (F5) a different token is generated every time.

Is this normal or not?

Comment: It's Normal action :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is completely Normal. No difference when a user is logged in or not.

Note that: Synchronizer token pattern is a technique where a token, secret and ***unique for each request***, is embedded by the web application in all HTML forms and verified on the server side. The token may be generated by any method that ensures unpredictability and ***uniqueness*** (e.g. using a hash chain of random seed). *The attacker is thus unable to place a correct token in his requests to authenticate them*